# Google Maps iOS SDK Parallax effect and Google logo issue

Tags: ios, google-maps, maps, parallax, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm rewriting an app with the Google Maps iOS SDK and i want to reproduce the parallax effect. I have my GMSMapView in a UITableViewCell and I did my parallax effect, but in the older versions (with MapKit) i've used a MapView as big as my tableview. With GMS i can't do that because, with this method, the Google logo is not yet visible and I think that google in this case can block my api key. If i use a MapView as big as my cell and i update my camera in function of the scrolling, the effect is not good because of rendering.

My question is: How i can do a good parallax effect with GMS, showing the Google logo? Is there a way to move the Google logo?

Thanks in advance